The bound of s-distance sets
Let $m(n,s)$ denote the maximum number of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that their pairwise distances take at most s values.Prove
$$\binom{n+1}{s} \le m(n,s) \le \binom{n+s+1}{s}$$
I tried to construct a series of polynomials which are linearly independent: let $A=\{a_1, \ldots , a_m\}$be such a set with distances $d_1, \ldots , d_s$.For each $i \in [m]$,we define $f_i(x) = \Pi_{k=1}^s (\|x-a_i\|^2-d_k^2)$, then $f_i(a_i) \neq 0, f_i(a_j) = 0 , \forall i \neq j$.So they are linearly independent in $\operatorname{span}\{f_1, \ldots, f_m\}$.But now I don't know how to calculate the dimension of $\operatorname{span}\{f_1, \ldots, f_m\}$ so that it is less than $\binom{n+s+1}{s}$ and bigger than $\binom{n+1}{s}$

I'm unconvinced the polynomial method will let you prove lower bounds on $m(n,s)$. However, a construction is not too hard to find.

For the lower boundary, just find a case of $\binom{n+1}s$ points in $\Bbb R^n$ which have $s$ or fewer distances.
